# C# ImageBox Clear Rectangle on MouseUp

Tags: c#, visual-studio, mouseevent, panel, picturebox

I have a panel with multiple picturebox created at runtime.

The user will create a rectangle on any picture box and the selected part will be displayed on a preview picturebox.

I have successfully done the above using the below code.

**Question**

1. I want to clear the selection rectangle at mouseup event. Used invalidate but not working.
   From [how to clear the graphics(rectangle shape) in picturebox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10442279/how-to-clear-the-graphicsrectangle-shape-in-picturebox)
2. Also, when I scroll the panel the same rectangle(mouse selection) is shown on all picturebox.

   ```
       private void Picture_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
   {
       if (Rect!=null && Rect.Width>0 && Rect.Height>0)
       {
           e.Graphics.FillRectangle(selectionBrush, Rect);
       }
   }

   private void Picture_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
   {
       RecStartpoint = e.Location;
       ((PictureBox)sender).Invalidate();
   }

   private void Picture_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
   {
       if (e.Button != MouseButtons.Left) return;

       Point tempEndPoint = e.Location;
       Rect.Location = new Point(
           Math.Min(RecStartpoint.X, tempEndPoint.X),
           Math.Min(RecStartpoint.Y, tempEndPoint.Y));
       Rect.Size = new Size(
           Math.Abs(RecStartpoint.X - tempEndPoint.X),
           Math.Abs(RecStartpoint.Y - tempEndPoint.Y));
       ((PictureBox)sender).Invalidate();
   }

   private void Picture_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
   {
       if (e.Button != MouseButtons.Left) return;

       PictureBox org_pic = (PictureBox)(sender);

       Point RecEndpoint=e.Location;


       int xDown = Math.Min(RecStartpoint.X,RecEndpoint.X);
       int yDown = Math.Min(RecStartpoint.Y, RecEndpoint.Y);
       int xUp = Math.Max(RecStartpoint.X,RecEndpoint.X);
       int yUp = Math.Max(RecStartpoint.Y,RecEndpoint.Y);

       Rectangle rec = new Rectangle(xDown, yDown, Math.Abs(xUp - xDown), Math.Abs(yUp - yDown));

       xDown = xDown * org_pic.Image.Width / org_pic.Width;
       yDown = yDown * org_pic.Image.Height / org_pic.Height;

       xUp = xUp * org_pic.Image.Width / org_pic.Width;
       yUp = yUp * org_pic.Image.Height / org_pic.Height;

       rectCropArea = new Rectangle(xDown, yDown, Math.Abs(xUp - xDown), Math.Abs(yUp - yDown));

       pictureBox_preview_photo.Refresh();
       Bitmap sourceBitmap = new Bitmap(org_pic.ImageLocation);
       Graphics g = pictureBox_preview_photo.CreateGraphics();
       g.DrawImage(sourceBitmap, new Rectangle(0, 0, pictureBox_preview_photo.Width, pictureBox_preview_photo.Height), rectCropArea, GraphicsUnit.Pixel);

   }
   ```

Comment: @devil_coder On MouseUp? Can't see the clear option.

Comment: Check few  more suggestions here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5856196/clear-image-on-picturebox

Where people recommended to set to NULL

Comment: @devil_coder I don't want to clear the picturebox, just the rectangle drawn.

Answer (score 0):

I would try this approach:

First, make `Image` variable, in the scope of form

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    //variable for holding original image, before rectangle is drawn on it
    Image originalImage = null;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    //rest of form's code...
```

second, save current picture in that variable on `MouseDown`

```
private void Picture_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    //save it
    startImage = ((PictureBox)sender).Image;
    RecStartpoint = e.Location;
    ((PictureBox)sender).Invalidate();
}
```

lastly, on the end of `MouseUp` event, set `Rectangle`'s width and height to zero and restore saved, original image

```
//snipped code
pictureBox_preview_photo.Refresh();
Bitmap sourceBitmap = new Bitmap(org_pic.ImageLocation);
Graphics g = pictureBox_preview_photo.CreateGraphics();
g.DrawImage(sourceBitmap, new Rectangle(0, 0, pictureBox_preview_photo.Width, pictureBox_preview_photo.Height), rectCropArea, GraphicsUnit.Pixel);

//make rectangle's widht and height 0 so that Paint event won't draw it
Rect.Width = Rect.Height = 0;
//restore image
this.Picture.Image = startImage;
```

I didn't understand that second question.

Comment: The problem with the above method is as there are multiple pictureboxes in panel . When I scroll the panel the rectangle is drawn automatically on the next picturebox as this is called private void Picture_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)